# Prove the following result on binomial coefficients

Tags: binomial-coefficients

If $(1+x)^n=^n\!\!C_0+^n\!\!C_1x+^n\!\!C_2x^2+\cdots+^n\!\!C_nx^n$, then show that
$$(^n\!\!C_0-^n\!\!C_2+^n\!\!C_4-^n\!\!C_6+\cdots)^2+(^n\!C_1-^n\!\!C_3+^n\!\!C_5-\cdots)^2\\
=^n\!\!C_0+^n\!\!C_1+^n\!\!C_2+\cdots+^n\!\!C_n$$
We have by putting, $x=1$,
$2^n=^n\!\!C_0+^n\!\!C_1+^n\!\!C_2+\cdots+^n\!\!C_n$.

Putting , $x=-1$,  we get 
$0=^n\!\!C_0-^n\!\!C_1+^n\!\!C_2-\cdots+(-1)^n \,^n\!\!C_n$.
 But how can I show that result? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put $x=i$ and $x=-i$ where $i=\sqrt{-1}$

Comment: You may try to find the absolute value of $(1+i)^{n}$.

Comment: the above two comments essentially are the answer